# How to get real file offset in NAND by file name?

Tags: linux, file-access, flash-memory, jffs2

Using linux, I can use raw access to NAND or access to files through filesystem. So, when I need to know, where my file is really located in NAND, what should I do? I cannot found any utilities providing this feature. Moreover, I cannot detect any possibility of this, besides hacking kernel with tons of "printk" (it's not nice way, I guess).
Can anybody enlighten me on this? (I'm using YAFFS2 and JFFS2 filesystems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a copy of any partition with `nanddump`.  Transfer that partition dump to a PC.  The *nandsim* utility can be used to mount the partitions on a PC.

```
modprobe nandsim first_id_byte=0x2c second_id_byte=0xda \
   third_id_byte=0x90 fourth_id_byte=0x95 parts=2,64,64
flash_erase /dev/mtd3 0 0
ubiformat /dev/mtd3 -f rootfs.ubi
```

This command emulates a Micron 256MB NAND flash with four partitions.  If you just capture the single partition and not the whole device, don't set parts.  You can also do `nanddump` on each partition and then concatenate them all.  This code targeted **mtd3** with a UbiFs partition.  For **JFFS2** or **YAFFS2**, you can try `nandwrite` or some other appropriate flashing utility on the PC.

> How to get real file offset in NAND by file name?

The files may span several *NAND sectors* and they are almost never contiguous.  There is not much of an advantage to keep file data together as there is no disk head that takes physical time to *seek*.  Some flash has marginally better efficiency for sequential reads; yet other flash will give better performance for reads from another erase block.

I would turn on *debug* at either the MTD layer or in the filesystem.  In a live system, the position of the file may migrate over time on the flash even if it is **not** written.  This is active wear leveling.

Comment: You can also mount the **PC** cloned file system as *read-only*.  If you wish to modify a file while a device is powered down and reflash it, then this would work.  It is hard to see how an answer to your question on a running system would be useful.